# Determining the convex hull in the presence of outliers

Tags: octave, scatter-plot, convex-hull

I made a software to create and optimize a racing line in a racetrack.
Now I want to integrate it using real data recorded from GPS, so I need to obtain the g-g diagram, where g is the acceleration. The real g-g diagram is a set of points, in a scatter graph. I need to obtain the contour of that scatter plot, to use it as boundary of limits accelerations.

To obtain data to work on it I recorded myself on two different racetrack.
The code I wrote translate the x-y coordinate to polar R-theta.
Then I divide the circle in a definite number of sector (say, 20).
I calculate the histogram of all R's values in each sector, then from histogram I take the last value with an acceptable number of samples.
Then I draw these lines, and this is the result:

[image]

[image]

It's not bad, but this boundary is a little inside from the real data, real acceleration is a little bit bigger. I cannot take only the max value, because in this way I take in consideration the absurd values (like 3g in right corner, for sure an error). Moreover, the limit change if I change the number of bins on the histogram, but I cannot find a way to choose the right number of bins.

How can I determine the "true" convex hull, ignoring the outliers?

Comment: It sounds like you'll want to look for a convex-hull with outlier detection. Octave has [convhull()](https://docs.octave.org/v4.4.0/Convex-Hull.html) implemented.

Comment: convhull lets you pass options right to the qhull library, is outlier detection/clipping something built in qhull?  i've never used it more than skin deep

Comment: I would go through all points, and simply delete the ones that have too few nearby neighbors (i.e. delete points where the local density is too low). There are many ways to do this, many choices to make along the way, so it's not a trivial solution, but I think it's the simplest approach.

Comment: By the way, your red line here is not a convex hull. It's not convex. Are you looking for the convex hull, or for the boundary of the points?

Comment: I'm looking for the boundary, not the convex boundary. Someone edited the title I wrote. How can I delete the points with density too low?